# А.С. Пушкин. Ода "Вольность"

Tags: литература

Назовите царя, о котором говорится в поэтических строках А.С. Пушкина:

О стыд! О ужас наших дней!

Как звери, вторглись янычары!...

Падут бесславные удары…

Погиб увенчанный злодей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, имеется в виду именно Павел1

Поэт — противник насилия. Свобода, с его точки зрения, не может быть достигнута в результате революции и заговора. Великую французскую революцию он называет «славной бедой» (казненный Людовик — «мученик ошибок славных»), подчеркнув ее разрушительный характер и одновременно указав на то, что революция — акт возмездия тиранам. Мрачная «диалектика» насилия над тиранами передана в словах об убийстве Павла I: «Падут бесславные удары... / Погиб увенчанный злодей».

Пустынный памятник тирана, // Забвенью брошенный дворец -- дворец Павла I (впоследствии Инженерный замок в Петербурге). Здесь был задушен император Павел I в ночь с 11 на 12 марта 1801 г. После этого события дворец долгие годы пустовал. Строфы Х и XI описывают убийство Павла.

Калигула (12--41) -- римский император, славившийся крайней жестокостью и убитый своими телохранителями; этим именем Пушкин называет Павла I. В стихе Погиб увенчанный злодей после слова "погиб" Пушкин нарисовал в одной из рукописей профиль Павла I.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас есть предположения?

Comment: Да,я предполагаю, что речь идёт о Павле I